# How to create duplicate project of an existing asp.net mvc 5 project

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created an asp.net mvc 5 project namely `ProjectA` in the directory `../Visual Studio 2015/Projects` , it has a dedicated database and working fine.

I want to create the replica of `ProjectA` as `ProjectB` in the same directory `../Visual Studio 2015/Projects`, with a different independent database from `ProjectA`.

Additionally, I've used Entity Framework Code First Approach.

How to achieve this? Any Help is deeply appreciated, Sorry in Advance, if this question seems silly and newbie kind of.. :)

Comment: Copy project a and save it under project b's name in the Projects folder.Go to web.config file and change the database connection to connect to the correct database.